# How to automate enabling remote access for mysql in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, bash

I know that I can enable remote access for MySql in Ubuntu by flowing this instructions:

```
cd /etc/mysql
cd mysql.conf.d
sudo nano mysqld.cnf

# edit file and comment out bind-address 127.0.0.1
# save and exit
```

How could I automate this change with command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use sed to remove the line from the file.

> sed -i '/bind-address/d' /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Then just make sure to restart the service.

Comment: And use `ssh` to get to the machine:  `ssh ... "sed ..."`

Answer (score 0):

When you need to make changes like this to a configuration file it is time take over control of that file with your automation or configuration management. This can be done in stages:

1. start by copying the modified file into your repo as a complete config file
2. modify your automation code to copy the file into place after installing the mysql package.  Don't forget to bounce mysql since Ubuntu started it for you with the default configs when it just got installed.
3. eventually you may want to turn the file into a template so you can make other changes to it.

Another way to handle this is to put your modified config file into a Debian package and install that from your automation code.